# Rollback SQL-Transaction in Owncloud App

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, doctrine, owncloud

I am developing an app for owncloud and am using the Owncloud API, not the App Framework.
In this environment I can start SQL-Transactions via `\OCP\DB::beginTransaction();` and I can commit the transaction cia `\OCP\DB::commit();`.

But I can't find a way to rollback a transaction. I googled it all day and searched through the Owncloud core files but couldn't find a way to do it.

Does anyone know how to do this? Right now I can just leave the transaction uncommited in my ajax requests, because they have only one transaction. But in other scripts I have to do multiple transactions one after another which are independent from another. I have to manually delete all my inserted rows in case anything goes wrong, which is not very nice.

Edit 2014/07/30:

I have found out that the `OC_DB_StatementWrapper`-Class, which is return by `\OCP\DB::prepare` of Owncloud does not provide a method to do this. However, it passes all unknown calls to the underlying `\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Statement`-object. This class is described here: [Doctrine.DBAL.Statement](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Statement.html)

It has a private `$_conn` (instance of [\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connection.html)) which has a method `rollback` to rollback a transaction. However, `$_conn` is private, so I can not access it.

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious but... I suppose you've tried `\OCP\DB::rollback();` and it doesn't exist :-?

Comment: Yes i tried that and it doesnt exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a solution myself. To those interested in how it works, here is the solution:

```
$conn = \OC::$server->getDatabaseConnection();
$conn->rollBack();
```

This will rollback the previously via `\OCP\DB::beginTransaction()` opened transaction. To start a new transaction, just call `\OCP\DB::beginTransaction()` again - works like a charm.